# How to get JavaScript variable value in C# code behind

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a gridview with a column with customised button.
When I click the button, user contact is asked for through JavaScript and then the contact is passed on to rowCommand event of gridview for some operation.

I am using Hiddenfield as a gridview column but there is something going wrong in setting and getting the value.

JavaScript code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateContact()
        {
        var contact = prompt("Please enter your contact number.");
        if (isEmpty(contact) && !isNumber(contact) && contact.length != 10)
            alert("Invalid contact.");
            return;
        else
            document.getElementById("hiddenCustomerContact.ClientID").value = contact;
    }
</script>
```

asp code:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gridSearchWorker" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"               OnRowCommand="gridSearchWorker_OnRowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gridSearchWorker_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="WORKER" HeaderText="WORKER" SortExpression="WORKER">
            <ItemStyle Width="12%" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnGetContact" runat="server" Text="Get Contact" CommandName="GetContact" OnClientClick="validateContact();" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CONTACT" HeaderText="CONTACT" SortExpression="CONTACT">
            <ItemStyle Width="12%" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenCustomerContact" runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="0.0001%" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

c# code behind:

```
    protected void gridSearchWorker_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "GetContact")
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cs);

            //ask for contact and check if any feedback pending
            HiddenField hiddenCustomerContact = 
                e.Row.FindControl("hiddenCustomerContact") as HiddenField; //getting error in this line


            string score = hiddenCustomerContact.Value;

            int n = Int32.TryParse(score, out val);
            string customerContact = "";

            //check if any feedback pending

            int pendingCount;

            if (pendingCount > 0)
            {
                //ask to give feedback

            }

            else
            {
                //show worker contact
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're using `getElementById("hiddenCustomerContact.ClientID")`, shouldn't it just be `getElementById("hiddenCustomerContact")`?

Comment: Ok...I will try removing ClinetID. But error is in code behind.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: I think you need to get the row. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748675/how-can-we-find-the-control-in-the-row-command-of-grid-view) helps?

Comment: @haldo It should be `getElementById("<%= hiddenCustomerContact.ClientID %>")` to get the element ID in webforms.

Comment: @Adriani6 thank you, it makes sense now :) I don't think that's his issue though. I think the problem is getting the element from code behind and the fact there is no `Row` in `GridViewCommandEventArgs`.  Need some feedback from OP really

Answer (score 0):

Hi it should work like this:
you can assign some value to the hidden variable as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var somefunction = function () {
            var hdnfldVariable = document.getElementById('hdnfldVariable');
            hdnfldVariable.value = 'value from javascript';
        }
    </script>
```

in code behind you can read this field variable:

```
string variable = hdnfldVariable.Value;
```